# How to optimize ruby method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, optimization, refactoring

I have the following ruby method which looks super ugly and i want to refactor this and reduce the perceived complexity for this.

```rb
def validate_hash_params(**kwargs)
  kwargs.each do |k, v|

    raise Sith::ProcessingError, "#{k} should be of type String" unless v&.is_a? String
    
    raise Sith::ProcessingError, "id length should be less than equal to 25" if kwargs[:id].length > 25

    raise Sith::ProcessingError, "info length should be less than equal to 100" if kwargs[:info].length > 100

    raise Sith::ProcessingError, "first_name length should be less than equal to 60" if kwargs[:first_name].length > 60

    raise Sith::ProcessingError, "email length should be less than equal to 50" if kwargs[:email].length > 50
    
    raise Sith::ProcessingError, "Invalid Email" unless Sith::EMAIL_REGEX.match(kwargs[:email])

    raise Sith::ProcessingError, "amount should contain digits with upto 2 decimal places" unless Sith::AMOUNT_REGEX.match(kwargs[:amount])

    [kwargs[:key1], kwargs[:key2], kwargs[:key3], kwargs[:key4], kwargs[:key5]].each do |key|
      raise SithError, "key length should be less than equal to 255" if key.length > 255
    end
  end
end
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "optimize"?

Comment: I would start to take a look at https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/10/ruby-case/

Comment: I'm confused. Most of the statements in the `|k,v|` loop are not functions of `k` or `v`, so they are merely repeated.

Comment: You tagged your question with ruby-on-rails. I wonder why you do not use [Rails model validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)?

Comment: Is `kwargs` going to be used to initialize a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Ruby on Rails I would suggest using [validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) rather than custom checks and raising exceptions. This requires making a little model.

```
class Sith
  include ActiveModel::Model
  
  attr_accessor :id, :info, :first_name, :email, :amount, :keys
  
  validates :id, length: { maximum: 25 }
  validates :info, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :first_name, length: { maximum: 60 }
  validates :email, length: { maximum: 50 }, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }
  validate :validate_amount_decimal_places
  validate :validate_keys

  private def validate_amount_decimal_places
    if amount != amount.round(2)
      errors.add(:amount, "amount should contain digits with upto 2 decimal places")
    end
  end

  private def validate_keys
    errors.add(:keys, "there can be, at most, 5 keys") if keys.size > 5
    
    if keys.any? { |key| key.length >= 255 }
      errors.add(:keys, "keys must be shorter than 255 characters")
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I combined the individual key1, key2, key3 parameters into a single key Array.

Now you can make `Sith` and check if it's valid.

```
sith = Sith.new(kwargs)
if !sith.valid?
  ...
end
```

If you wish to use exceptions, use [Strict Validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#strict-validations).

```
validates :id, length: { maximum: 25, strict: Sith::ProcessingError }
```

---

However, a lot of these "validations" seem unnecessary and possibly prohibitive. Why limit the length of someone's email?

Comment: This works! Don't know why i didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

You might reorganize your calculations as follows. If necessary, the various validations could of course be reordered.

```
def validate(**kwargs)
  validate_values_are_strings(**kwargs)
  validate_max_lengths(**kwargs)
  validate_amount(kwargs[:amount])
  validate_max_key_lengths(**kwargs)
  validate_email_pattern(kwargs[:email])
end
```

```
def validate_values_are_strings(**kwargs)
  kwargs.each do |k,v|
    raise Sith::ProcessingError,
      "value of #{k} should be of type String" unless v.is_a? String
  end
end
```

```
def validate_max_lengths(**kwargs)
  k,v = { id: 24, info: 100, first_name: 60, email: 50 }.find do |k,v|
    kwargs[k].length > v
  end
  raise Sith::ProcessingError,
    "#{k.to_s} length should be less than or equal to #{v}" unless k.nil?
end
```

```
def validate_amount(amount)
  raise Sith::ProcessingError,
    "amount should contain digits with upto 2 decimal places" unless
      Sith::AMOUNT_REGEX.match?(amount)
end
```

```
def validate_max_key_lengths(**kwargs)
   raise SithError, "key length should be less than equal to 255" if
     [:key1, :key2, :key3].map { |k| kwargs[k].length }.max > 255
end
```

```
def validate_email_pattern(email)
  raise Sith::ProcessingError, "Invalid Email" unless
    Sith::EMAIL_REGEX.match?(email)
end
```

Suppose:

```
kwargs =
  { id: '23', info: '99', first_name: '59', email: 'hank@some_url.com',
    amount: '2.63', key1: 'cow', key2: 'chicken', key3: 'goat' }
```

Let's examine simplifications of some of these methods.

```
def validate_values_are_strings(**kwargs)
  kwargs.each do |k,v|
    raise "value of #{k} should be of type String" unless v.is_a? String
  end
end

validate_values_are_strings(**kwargs)
  #=> nil (no errors)
validate_values_are_strings(**(kwargs.merge(email: 7)))
  #=> RuntimeError (value of email should be of type String)
```

```
def validate_max_key_lengths(**kwargs)
   raise "key length should be less than equal to 255" if
     [:key1, :key2, :key3].map { |k| kwargs[k].length }.max > 255
end

validate_max_key_lengths(**kwargs)
  #=> nil (no errors)
validate_max_key_lengths(**(kwargs.merge(key2: 'a'*256)))
  #=> RuntimeError (key length should be less than equal to 255)
```

```
def validate_amount(amount)
  raise "amount should contain digits with upto 2 decimal places" unless
      /\A\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\z/.match?(amount)
end

validate_amount(kwargs[:amount])
  #=> nil (no errors)
validate_amount("2.634")
  #=> RuntimeError (amount should contain digits with upto 2 decimal places)
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def validate_hash_params(**kwargs)
  validate_string(kwargs)
  validate_length(kwargs, :id, 25)
  validate_length(kwargs, :info, 100)
  validate_length(kwargs, :first_name, 60)
  validate_length(kwargs, :email, 50)

  raise Sith::ProcessingError, 'Invalid Email' unless Sith::EMAIL_REGEX.match(kwargs[:email])
  raise Sith::ProcessingError, 'amount should contain digits with upto 2 decimal places' unless Sith::AMOUNT_REGEX.match(kwargs[:amount])
  validate_key_length(kwaargs)
end

def validate_length(kwargs, key, length)
  raise Sith::ProcessingError, "id length should be less than equal to #{length}" if kwargs[key].length > length
end

def validate_string(kwargs)
  not_a_string = kwargs.find { |_k, v| !v.is_a?(String) }

  raise Sith::ProcessingError, "#{not_a_string.first} should be of type String" if not_a_string
end

def validate_key_length(kwargs)
  raise SithError, 'key length should be less than equal to 255' if [:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4, :key5].any? { |k| kwargs[k].length > 255 }
end
```